# Hibernate: How to map to static table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, mapping

I have the role and permission tables with a join table role_permission using the annotation:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="ROLE_PERMISSION", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="permission_id"))


ROLE                 ROLE_PERMISSION     PERMISSION (Static)
--------             -----------          --------
id ------------------ role_id
rolename              permission_id ----- id
description                               permission_name    
---------             ----------          --------
```

The thing is, the permission is already filled with records and it should be read only.

How can I populate ROLE_PERMISSION join table without having another object and without having to store data in the static permission table?

I would greatly appreciate some expert advice.

Comment: You may have to use DTO.To be more accurate create a DTO object, assume ROLE_PERMISSIONDto, that will contain only the object of Role and permission and try to transform your query result using Hibernate `Transformer`.

Comment: Unless you REALLY need it to be application level, I would instead do it directly in the db. Just write  a SQL script that will be executed on application start.

Comment: hi @Amogh - i just need to write on the ROLE_PERMISSION table.

Comment: hi @SpartanElite- it should really be in the application level.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieved it, Please suit yourselves if you want a OnetoMany dependency or a ManyToMany dependency User-> Role.

So the basic idea is :

1. Create table User & SystemRole in the database and add entries to the static table SystemRole.
2. Ensure that the SystemRole has no constructor to instantiate any Role.
3. Whenever you want to asscociate any Role with a User simply use a method which will take an input as the UserName and return the UserRole Object.
   Simply use a query to retrieve these details , I havent added these details here since i am using Springboot Application which uses a CrudRepository.
4. Lastly ensure that the dependency(manytomany/onetoMany) doesnt have a cascade type since Systemrole is already saved.

**User.java:**

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, Set<SystemRole> roles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<SystemRole> roles;

    public Set<SystemRole> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<SystemRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    public int isEnabledasInt() {
        return enabled ? 1 : 0;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = (1 == enabled) ? true : false;
    }

}
```

**SystemRole.java :**

```
package com.spring.security.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "System_Role")
public class SystemRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    private SystemRole() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SystemRole)) return false;

        SystemRole that = (SystemRole) o;

        if (getId() != that.getId()) return false;
        return getName().equals(that.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + getName().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```